# Spring3, Hibernate, MySQL - How do I add transactions control?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Spring3, Hibernate, MySQL - How do I add transactions control??

I would like to find out how to add transaction control to the following so if one of the calls do make it both get roll back?

```
public void saveFriend(Friend friend, String rUser) 
{
   friend.setId(1);
   friend.setUsername(rUser);
   friend.setAddedDate(new Date());
   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(friend);

   friend.setId(2):
   friend.setUsername(rUser);
   friend.setAddedDate(new Date());
   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(friend);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void saveFriend(Friend friend, String rUser) 
{
   Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
   friend.setId(1);
   friend.setUsername(rUser);
   friend.setAddedDate(new Date());
   session.saveOrUpdate(friend);

   friend.setId(2):
   friend.setUsername(rUser);
   friend.setAddedDate(new Date());
   session.saveOrUpdate(friend);

   if(someCondition) {
      t.commit();
   }
   else{
      t.rollback();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[The Spring manual has a *huge* amount of information on how you can manage transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), either programmatically (as in RollingBoy's post) or declaratively with annotations or AOP.

You are best off reviewing the documentation first to understand how it works.